# Android Webview Blank Page

Tags: android, webview

my aplication is working in some phones perfectly but in the some phones, just it seems white screen... I think it's about the XML codes... Codes are below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: don't you have a root layout for this?

Comment: No i dont have... How can create root layout can you explain? @Lal

Comment: root layout...i mean..try wrapping your `WebView` inside a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Okay thank you i try something but i still see white screen some phones :( I wonder Could it be related to XML code?

Comment: Try this `android:layout_width="match_parent"`
    `android:layout_height="match_parent"` can you show how you defined your webview?